# Expressing a positive semi-definite matrix as sum of a diagonal and a rank one projector

Tags: positive-definite

Let $A\geq0$ be an  $n\times n$ positive semi-definite matrix over $\mathbb{C}$, i.e., $x^* Ax\geq 0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{C}^n$. Given $A$, is it always possible to find real numbers $\alpha,\beta\geq0$, a diagonal matrix $D\geq 0$, and a vector $y\in \mathbb{C}^n$ such that $$A=\alpha D+\beta\, yy^*\,? $$

Probably it is not always possible, but I could not find an example.

Comment: nope....it is not positive semi definite over $\mathbb{C}$, as it is not Hermitian.  A counterexample, if exists, must be for $n\geq 3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition implies that by just changing the diagonal elements of $A$, we can make a rank $1$ operator out of $A$ (in other words, the columns will span a one-dimensional space).

Clearly, this will almost never work; for a concrete counterexample, you could just take a $4\times 4$ matrix with a $2\times 2$ block of full rank
in the upper right corner.

Comment: Sorry I misread..."upper right". Let me check..

Comment: @Poor.Jack: Any symmetric matrix with sufficiently large diagonal entries is (trivially) positive definite.

Comment: Now I see. Thank you for your help!

Comment: If you don't mind for this request, could you please share your thought on my another similar [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1829694/subtracting-a-diagonal-psd-matrix-from-a-given-psd-matrix).